# Difference between HTTP web form POST and HTML button submit clicked

Tags: php, html

I'd like to know what is the difference between HTTP web form POST and button submit click, are they having totally different functioning or they are identical to each other?

I have fiddler, where I tried to emulate the incoming and ongoing POST and GET statements, POST sends the request and concatenate the input area parameters at the end of request, but that still doesn't give me clue whether, POST and sumbmit are identical or not.

Comment: What do you mean by `submit`? Do you mean `<input type="submit">`?

Comment: Submit buttons are nothing if they are not inside a form so i'm not quite sure what you're asking here?

Comment: I mean this `<button class = "any_button_name"    type= "submit " >Send email> </button> `

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt In my case yes they are inside Form.

Comment: @Sonya well, it depends... if you have `<form action="post">` then HTTP POST is used, if you have `action="get"` then HTTP GET is used. There is no functional difference between any HTTP POST and the one sent via `form` using the `submit` button. After all, HTTP as a protocol defines how it works, if you want your POST to work, you must follow these specifications. Anything else would just fail or produce unexpected results.

Comment: One thing that always I got puzzled in my mind, how about if form has more than one submit button how the server side behaves and knows how to handle them in which order ?

Comment: When you click a submit button, say `<input type="submit" name="test" value="send">`, then the server will receive the key-value pair `test='send'`. If there is another submit button, the server will not be aware of it. Only the `name` and `value` of a clicked button is sent.

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP POST:**

- It is one of the `HTTP` method to send your data to your respective
  script path.
- This is the secure method where data is not being shown
  in the URL as `HTTP GET` method.
- The data will be send to the desired script via
  the headers.

**SUBMIT BUTTON CLICK :**

- It is one of the event of web form through which the data into the
  form inputs will get posted to the script path present in the
  `action` attribute of form.

Now what will happen if the form has the two submit buttons?

First thing is that this is the rare case when we need two submit buttons because we can click one button at a time only.

Lets say we have following two buttons in some demo form as follow

```
<form name="profileForm" action="saveprofile.php" method = "POST">
          // Your input fields go here 
 <button class = "any_button_name" type= "submit " name ="save_profile" value ="save_profile" >Save Profile </button>

 <button class = "any_button_name" type= "submit " value="preview_profile"  name ="preview_profile" >Preview Profile </button>

</form>
```

> Here in code `value` attribute has been added to know which button has been clicked.

Now at PHP Side you can checked the which button has been clicked.

```
// code from saveprofile.php
if('save_profile' == $_POST['save_profile']) {
    // save profile code
}

if('preview_profile' == $_POST['preview_profile']) {
    // save profile code
}
```

Hope this may help to clear your doubts.